# Access Queries in Visual Studio with Devexpress

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

I have recently decided to re-develop an access VBA application in VB .net with DevExpress.

I have managed to figure out databinding with the raw tables. However, I am struggling with the queries.

I have tried the query builder, but I dont have the option to save them and bind object to it. I assume it works this way? As it did in access? Or is the query builder there simply to help you format the SQL text?

I am trying to bind a DataGrid to a simply join query without any luck.

Can you someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: Without some example of code, which shows where you struggling, it difficult to help you.

Comment: can you explain step by step what you are trying to do and where you are stuck ? There are many ways to use queries in visual studio so if you dont tell us how you are trying to do this than no one can help you with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main approaches that I can think of.  One is to use datatables, and the other is to use domain objects.

Datatables are quick to write, can easily handle most of the heavy lifting for you (including CRUD operations) and are pretty scalable, as changes to the underlying object can be handled relatively easily.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
```

Domain Objects (aka POCOs) take a lot of up-front work but typically in the log run make for a more bulletproof and robust solution.  Plus, there are frameworks and even Micro ORMs that will do much of the heavy lifting for you, if you choose to use them.

```
List<DomainObject> do = new List<DomainObject>();
```

These work with tables, views or queries.  You mention you have this figured out for a table, so I'm guessing you have already sort-of gotten this far.

So, first step -- figure out which direction you want to go.  (pick domain objects)

Second step -- I recommend using a binding source (System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource).  Make your data table / collection the `DataSource` for the binding source.

Third step, make the binding source the data source for your grid.  If you are using a Domain Object, you'll see the columns populate automatically.

From there, once the datatable or collection is populated, you can assign it as the data source for the binding source, and .NET and Dev Express will take care of the rest for you.

```
bindingSource1.DataSource = dt;
```

or

```
bindingSource1.DataSource = do;
```

Now if you're talking CRUD operations -- that's a horse of a different color.  You still use these as building blocks, but this is in no way a comprehensive answer for that.

By the way, the code above is C#, so you need minor tweaks to get this to be VB.  I don't speak VB, otherwise I would have just done it like that to begin with.